# Solve the differential equation (if exact): $(5x + 4y)dx + (4x - 8y^3)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to test this to see if it is exact. My conclusion is the it is indeed exact because $My = 4 = Nx$. then I integrated $Mdx$ and $Ndy$.

$$
\int Mdx = \int (5x+4y)\, dx = (5/2)x^2 + 4xy +f(y)
$$
$$\int Ndy = \int (4x-8y^3)\, dy = 4xy-2y^4 + g(x) 
$$

What am I supposed to conclude in regards to the $4xy$ being present in both equations? Does this mean that my final answer is $$(5/2)x^2 - 2y^4 + 4xy + C = 0$$ or $$(5/2)x^2 - 2y^4 + 8xy + C = 0$$

??

Comment: $4x$ and $4y$ suggest that it should be $4xy$.

Comment: @CheeHan Why can we make this conclusion? I'm only just at the level of Differential Equations in my mathematics journey so I'm not yet fully aware of why we can justify this.

Comment: By definition, your differential equation is said to be exact if you can find a function $\varphi=\varphi(x,y)$ such that $\varphi_x(x,y)=5x+4y$ and $\varphi_y(x,y)=4x-8y^3$, where $\varphi_x$ and $\varphi_y$ are the partial derivative of $\varphi$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively. If you are using your method, you are essentially integrating $5x+4y$ (which is $\varphi_x$) over $x$ and $4x-8y^3$(which is $\varphi_y$) over $y$, so all you need to do after that is to find $g(x)$ or $h(y)$ by comparing the two expression, not adding them up (:

Comment: @CheeHan very detailed response thanks! A quick follow up question - why do you say "find $g(x)$ _or_ $h(y)$" though? I am solving another problem and after integrating my integrals ended up with a $g(x)$ and $h(y)$. I see that the $g(x)$ "matches up" with a term involving $x$ on the other solved integral, but the $h(y)$ has no matching $y$ term on the other side!.....Ohhhh is this where the constant $C$ comes from??

Comment: It should be $f(y)$ according to your notation, and it does; $f(y)$ corresponds to the term involving $y$ only which is $-2y^4$. Also, the constant comes from the fact differentiating a constant gives you zero. So you should really have 2 arbitrary constant, $C_1$ and $C_2$, say for your first two equations after you integrate; but then when you patch up things altogether, they are just an arbitrary constant, so people usually just put a $C$ after they found $\varphi$. Note that $C$ is determined by the initial condition (if you are given one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could differentiate your answer, substitute back into your equation and find out yourself which one it is.

Comment: I think your answer led me on the right track. Looking at both answers it seems clear now that if I wanted to differentiate it back to the original equation (in the title) the one with $8xy$ won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rule which almost always works: (You can differentiate the solution to check). Integrate $M$ with respect to $x$ keeping $y$ as a constant and integrate only those terms of $N$ which do not involve $x$ with respect to $y$. Sum the result and equate to a constant.

So as $\displaystyle\int_{y\mbox{ constant}}Mdx=\int(5x+4y)dx=\frac{5x^2}{2}+4xy$, and $\displaystyle\int\mbox{(Terms of $N$ free of $x$) } dy=-8\int y^3dy=-2y^4$ we have $\frac{5x^2}{2}+4xy-2y^4=c$ as the solution.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Why does this method not involve testing for exactness first? Also, at the end should I always just throw a constant in there somewhere?

Comment: This was done under the assumption that exactness has already been tested and found. You can just throw in the constant on the right hand side.

Comment: Noted. I will practice using this method to expand my toolbox of knowledge. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you may solve it directly:
\begin{align}
(5x+4y)\,dx + (4x-8y^3)\,dy&=5x\,dx + (4y\,dx+4x\,dy) - 8y^3\,dy=\\
&=d(5x^2/2) + d(4xy)-d(2y^4),
\end{align}
and
$$5x^2/2 + 4xy-2y^4=C.$$

Or we can take
$$
\int Mdx = \int (5x+4y)\, dx = (5/2)x^2 + 4xy +f(y)
$$
and differentiate it:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\int Mdx = 4x +f'(y) = 4x-8y^3 \Longrightarrow f'(y) = -8y^3
$$
and then $f(y) = -2y^4 + C$.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf hint: $ differentiate the right hand side of $(1)$ with respect to $y$ and set it to $4x - 8y^3.$   that should allow you to find $f$ unto a constant.